# Is it ok to texture paint the space between UV islands

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I use photoshop to paint textures on UV map, since it seems like it doesn't affect the mesh, I also paint the space between UV islands, the UV map itself looks messy. Is it okay to leave it like this? If not is there a easy way to delete the overflow in the space between islands

[image: Image of UV map and mesh]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not only OK, it's probably what you want to do. Image will have to be resampled while rendering in order to display it on your 3d object, so if you have a texture that ends exactly on your UV seams, some of it outside your UV map might get sampled sometimes and you will see some lines at your seams. It's better to extend your textures further than the edges of your UV islands to avoid this.